# Javascript Function on PHP returned results, duplicate ID issue

Tags: javascript, php, function

I was wondering if anyone could kindly help me or steer me in the right direction with this one...Basically I have a Javascript function which calculates the total number between a ticket price (from mysql database) and the quantity (from a drop-down menu). The Javascript and PHP work fine...but only for the first result, the functionality is not dynamic and really need help fixing this.

In my PHP, a table is returned from an SQL statement:

```
$postCodeSQL = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE locationID IN (SELECT locationID FROM location WHERE postCode LIKE '$pcSearch') ";

$postCoderesult = mysql_query($postCodeSQL) or die(mysql_error());

  while ($pcRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($postCoderesult)) {
                                $ID = $pcRow['ticketID']; //row in ticket table on database
                                $venue = $pcRow['venue'];
                                $ticketPrice = $pcRow['tPrice'];
                                $date = $pcRow['date'];
                                $time= $pcRow['time'];

                        echo "<tr>\n";
                                echo "<td id=\"venuePlace\">$venue <input type='hidden' id='venuePlaceHidden' class='venuePlaceHidden' value='".$venue."'></td>\n";
                                echo "<td id=\"ticketprice\">&pound;$ticketPrice <input type='hidden' id='ticketPriceHidden' class='ticketPriceHidden' value='".$ticketPrice."'></td>\n";
                                echo "<td >
                                        <select name =\"showQuantity\" id=\"showQuantity\" class =\"showQuantity\" onChange=\"calculateCost()\" >
                                                <option value=\"Select\">Select...</option>
                                                <option value=\"1\">1</option>
                                                <option value=\"2\">2</option>
                                                <option value=\"3\">3</option>
                                                <option value=\"4\">4</option>
                                                <option value=\"5\">5</option>
                                        </select>

                                    </td>\n";
                                echo "<td id=\"date\">$date <input type='hidden' id='dateHidden' class='dateHidden' value='".$date."'></td>\n";
                                echo "<td id=\"time\">$time <input type='hidden' id='timeHidden' class='timeHidden' value='".$time."'></td>\n";

                                echo "<td> <input type= \"button\" class= \"buyMe\" value= \"Buy\" name=\"buyMe\" onclick=\"grandTotal()\" > 
                                      </td>\n";


                        echo "</tr>\n";

                        }
```

The hidden fields are inserted so the Javascript functions can parse these values. The JS function parses these values and multiplies the cost of the ticket ($ticketPrice) and multiplies it a delivery value:

```
function quantityChange() {
//Select the value of the drop down list       
var quantity = $('.showQuantity option:selected').val();
//get the value of the number from the tPrice column in 'ticket' table
var ticket = parseInt(document.getElementById('ticketPriceHidden').value);
//get the venue value
var venue = document.getElementById('venuePlaceHidden').value;
var date = document.getElementById('dateHidden').value;
var time = document.getElementById('timeHidden').value;
//multiply them together
var total = quantity * ticket;

return {
    venue: venue,
    quantity: quantity,
    ticket: ticket,
    date: date,
    time: time,
    total: total
};
}

function calculateCost () {
var data = quantityChange();

$('#summary').html('You have chosen '+ ' '  + data.quantity  + ' ' + 'tickets @' + ' ' + data.venue + ' = '  + ' ' +  '&pound;' + data.total);
}
```

As stated before, this function works for the top result returned by the table, however in my table there are more than one result returned and the JS doesn't work on these values. my problem is related with duplicate IDs because each result returned has the same ID.

I've given each result a class but I cannot do a 'getElementByClass' method.
Please please please does anyone know how to edit this code so the JS functions will work for the other results returned? I have a feeling that I may possibly need a foreach() loop to state 'for each value that is returned, apply the JS function...' or something along those lines?

Any help is really appreciated and I am working on improving my accept rate!

Comment: First it strikes before proceeding..shouldn't your query be changed to ` "SELECT tkt.* FROM ticket tkt, location loc WHERE tkt.locationID =loc.locationID  and loc.postCode LIKE '$pcSearch' "` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the SQL works perfectly fine and is not the problem. The problem lies in the returning the duplicate ID in the PHP and not being able to achieve dynamic behaviour.

Comment: You are setting duplicate IDs for the <td> and <input> elements.Instead concat $ID to the id of the elements your create.

Comment: That's a good idea, i'll give that a try...where would I try concat $ID in the code? i.e. echo "<td id=\"venuePlace\">$venue....
This would be echo "<td id=\".$ID.\">$venue...*rest of code* 
??

Answer (score 1):

Try this code with dynamic Id......

```
<script>
function quantityChange(id) {
//Select the value of the drop down list       
var quantity = $('.showQuantity_'+id+'option:selected').val();
//get the value of the number from the tPrice column in 'ticket' table
var ticket = parseInt(document.getElementById('ticketPriceHidden_'+id).value);
//get the venue value
var venue = document.getElementById('venuePlaceHidden_'+id).value;
var date = document.getElementById('dateHidden_'+id).value;
var time = document.getElementById('timeHidden_'+id).value;
//multiply them together
var total = quantity * ticket;

    $('#summary_'+id).html('You have chosen '+ ' '  + quantity  + ' ' + 'tickets @' + ' ' + venue + ' = '  + ' ' +  '&pound;' + total);
}


</script>

<?php 

$postCodeSQL = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE locationID IN (SELECT locationID FROM location WHERE postCode LIKE '$pcSearch') ";
$postCoderesult = mysql_query($postCodeSQL) or die(mysql_error());

$i=0;
while ($pcRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($postCoderesult)) {
    $ID = $pcRow['ticketID']; //row in ticket table on database
    $venue = $pcRow['venue'];
    $ticketPrice = $pcRow['tPrice'];
    $date = $pcRow['date'];
    $time= $pcRow['time'];

echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td id=\"venuePlace\">$venue <input type='hidden' id='venuePlaceHidden_$i' class='venuePlaceHidden' value='".$venue."'></td>\n";
echo "<td id=\"ticketprice\">&pound;$ticketPrice <input type='hidden' id='ticketPriceHidden_$i' class='ticketPriceHidden' value='".$ticketPrice."'></td>\n";
echo "<td >
<select name =\"showQuantity\" id=\"showQuantity_$i\" class =\"showQuantity\" onChange=\"quantityChange($i)\" >
<option value=\"Select\">Select...</option>
<option value=\"1\">1</option>
<option value=\"2\">2</option>
<option value=\"3\">3</option>
<option value=\"4\">4</option>
<option value=\"5\">5</option>
</select>

</td>\n";
echo "<td id=\"date\">$date <input type='hidden' id='dateHidden_$i' class='dateHidden' value='".$date."'></td>\n";
echo "<td id=\"time\">$time <input type='hidden' id='timeHidden_$i' class='timeHidden' value='".$time."'></td>\n";

echo "<td> <input type= \"button\" class= \"buyMe\" value= \"Buy\" name=\"buyMe\" onclick=\"grandTotal()\" > 
</td>\n";


echo "</tr>\n";
$i++;
echo "<div id = 'summary_$i'></div>";
}
?>
```

> Explanation

```
<script>
function abc(id){
  alert('#ticketPriceHidden_'+id);
  var tph =  document.getElementById('ticketPriceHidden_'+id).value;

 if(tph == ''){
     alert('this field is required......');
 }

}
</script>


<a href="javascript:;" onclick="abc(1);">1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="abc(2);">2</a>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks very much for your help, I think i'm on the right lines however I keep getting an error: document.getElementById("ticketPriceHidden_" + id) is null
Do you have any ideas by any chance? Thanks

Comment: document.getElementById("ticketPriceHidden_" + id) is null.

Coming from: var ticket = parseInt(document.getElementById('ticketPriceHidden_'+id).value);
Sorry if I was unclear about that the first time.

Comment: Ah I think I understand what you're trying to show me. I have a problem in my PHP because with each result that is returned, an input button is also added to the table. So if I try to declare: onChange = quantityChange(1)...this would only apply to the first result and the other results would follow suit. I'm really sorry, i'm terrible at trying to explain this type of thing! Basically the input button I have in the first row works but the second button that is returned doesn't show the right values. :/ I'm starting to confuse myself now haha.

Comment: Also I didn't mention and don't know if it will help but the venues and ticket prices are stored on mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then one set of same IDs (for different result), then good idea is to use them with numbers: `venuePlaceHidden_01, venuePlaceHidden_02`

So you  need to add circle and incrementing `$num` variable both in your code for creating table, and the code of analize the values in JS.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The PHP above is applicable for all results returned in that table so result 2 in the table will also have an ID of 'ticketPriceHidden', 'venuePlaceHidden' etc. so when the JS function is called, it only works for the 1st result returned. I need a way of passing the $ID to each result returned so each returned result have their own values, if that makes any sense?

Comment: So there is the problem, which you need to solve, and what I have pointed in my unswer: you need to change code so, that result 2 will have IDs with index 2 and so on, same for JS processing code. This is general solution for multiple results pages, which is simple to realise, clear to understand and working good!